# Why doesn't console.log work when passed as a parameter to forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, foreach

This is just out of curiosity, but do any of you have an idea why this code won't work?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(console.log);

// Prints 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation' in Chrome
```

On the other hand, this seems to work fine:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach(function(n) { console.log(n) });
```

So... ?

Comment: Indeed. Will answer it myself, I'm such an idiot

Comment: Can it just be deleted? It's not really that helpful =/

Comment: @PabloFernandez I meant the question, but I guess someone liked it enough to upvote so maybe it was useful to someone after all... It's never clear to me if upvotes are from people finding the question genuinely useful, or just from answerers trying to game the system.

Comment: @GGG Fine with me, but you think that's really necessary? it got 2 upvotes... perhaps we can close it as a duplicate of a question that talks about `bind` in js?

Comment: It would probably be best to close as a dupe of a question about how `this` is resolved... there are other ways than `bind` to work around it.

Comment: Why close it? This is a really interesting brain teaser. In fact, I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Compare the output of these in chrome's console: `[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(console.log.bind(console));` ... `[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function(x){console.log(x)});`

Comment: @BrandonBoone yeah, maybe I'm wrong. It might be an unusual enough case that it's hard to tell what's going on at first.

Comment: yep, this is a good question. @PabloFernandez - I am guessing you got inspiration for this question after reading "Async Javascript" book by Trevor Burnham - page 13 - precisely the same example code :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually as @SLaks pointed out, console.log seems to be using `this` internally and when it's passed as a parameter `this` now refers to the array instance.

The workaround for that is simply:

`var c = console.log.bind(console);`
`[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(c);`

Answer (score 31):

It's worth pointing out that there is a difference in behavior in the implementation of `console.log`.  Under node v0.10.19 you do not get an error; you simply see this:

```
> [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(console.log);
1 0 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
2 1 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
3 2 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
4 3 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
5 4 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

This is because the callback to `forEach` is a three-parameter function taking the value, the index, and the array itself.  The function `console.log` sees those three parameters and dutifully logs them.

Under the Chrome browser console, however, you get

```
> [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(console.log);
TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

and in this case, `bind` *will* work:

```
 > [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(console.log.bind(console));
 1 0 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
 2 1 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
 3 2 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
 4 3 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
 5 4 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

but there is an alternative way: note that the *second parameter to `forEach`* takes the value of `this` to use in the callback:

```
> [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(console.log, console)
1 0 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
2 1 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
3 2 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
4 3 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
5 4 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

which works in the Chrome console and node for me.  Of course, I'm sure what you *want* is just the values, so I'm afraid the best solution is, indeed:

```
> [1,2,3,4,5].forEach(function (e) {console.log(e)});
1
2
3
4
5
```

Whether node's behavior is a bug, or it simply takes advantage of the fact that `console.log` is not specified by ECMA is interesting in its own right.  But the varying behavior, and the fact that you have to be aware of whether your callback uses `this` is important and means we have to fall back to direct coding, even if it is verbose thanks to the keyword `function`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation - readers might find the following link which describes the expected arguments to Array.prototype.forEach(), and the args passed to the supplied callback (as you discussed): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Though with arrow functions you can use: `[1,2,3].forEach(v=>console.log(v))`. ;-)

Comment: Indeed, I can’t believe I was still using the long-form function expression as arguments to `forEach` (and friends) in early 2014. Must have switched over shortly after, though.

Comment: This is still valid as of the current LTS version of node (v16). Seems like it will stay like this forever?

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that JS allows both arrow and non-arrow functions? Yes they will co-exist forever because they are very different creatures, though in this particular case (since there is no `this` involved, essentially), either can be used but the arrow form is preferred. But in most cases they are not the same: methods require non-arrow functions and callbacks within methods should be arrow-functions, to cite the most common example.

Answer (score 13):

This works:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach(console.log.bind(console));
```

Comment: great answer, I'd like to mark it as accepted but could you explain (for those who don't know) what your code does? If not I'm afraid I'll have to accept mine which is a bit more informative. Thanks

Comment: Does not work in Node v6: 

    > [1,2,3].forEach(console.log.bind(console))
    1 0 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    2 1 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    3 2 [ 1, 2, 3 ]

Comment: Still failing in Node v7. I would avoid this solution if you want simply to log the elements of the array. This answer applies `console.log` to the three parameters of the callback and prints out very messy and undesirable output. It probably did work back when the answer was written though, but only because the particular JavaScript implementation was wrong, IMHO. The callback takes three parameters these days.

Answer (score -5):

I can't say I've seen that syntax, but my guess is because log expects a parameter, being the message/object/etc to log in the console.

in the first example, you are just passing a function reference to forEach, which is fine if your function doesn't expect paramater which make the function behave as expected.  In the second example you pass in e and then log it.

Comment: Wrong; `forEach` is passing a parameter.

Comment: the point I was trying to make though is that the parameter needs to be passed to console.log though, i.e. console.log(_e_)

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what happens.  There is no difference between a function from a function expression and a function from a property.