# why can't you do [array].forEach(console.log)

Tags: javascript

going back to writing javascript for the time being, i wonder why this isn't possible

```
[array].forEach(console.log)
```

Comment: what is the value of `array`

Comment: you can write your own prototype. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/prototypes-in-javascript--net-24949

Comment: You can do that (just did it in Firebug), as long as `array` is defined.  Are you just not getting back what you expected?  What were you expecting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't console.log work when passed as a parameter to forEach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639167/why-doesnt-console-log-work-when-passed-as-a-parameter-to-foreach)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work correctly in certain browsers and not in others.

A major point of confusion in Javascript is the way `this` behaves. Often these will produce vastly different behavior:

```
myObj.method();

var a = myObj.method;
a();
```

What you are doing there is passing `console.log` as a function into `forEach`, which is separating it from the object it is attached to. This will cause any uses of `this` inside the `log` method to refer to the wrong thing, and quite possibly cause the method to not work correctly.

To remedy this, you can pass a `thisArg` into `.forEach`:

```
[array].forEach(console.log, console);
```

or use `.bind()`:

```
[array].forEach(console.log.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `console.log.bind(console)`, otherwise the `.log()` method of a `console` object is invoked with a wrong context.

The general rule to follow is: the method must be called with a proper context unless it's stated otherwise.

So in this particular case no one states it can be invoked with say `undefined`, so you should not expect it to work. And even if it does - you should not rely on it.

Comment: thanks, I always thought that context is provided if it is a method on an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can, if the browser supports it, although even then you shouldn't rely on it.

The reason it doesn't work on *some* browsers is that passing a function reference like this (even if that function is a property of an object such as `console`) doesn't set the `this` context correctly within that function.

When the (browser specific) implementation of the `log` function tries to access its `this` variable it finds that instead of referring to `console` it actually refers to the global object.

To fix it, you can use this:

```
[array].forEach(console.log.bind(console));
```

where the `.bind` call returns a new function wrapping the original function and whose context is set to the passed parameter (e.g. `console`)