# Creating a repeat method

Tags: javascript

I've made a little method to easily repeat a function several times (instead of using loops, cause they are long and tiring, at least for me).

```js
Function.prototype.repeat = function(count,params) {
while(count--) this.apply(this, params);
};

document.write.repeat(4,["Hi"]);
```

I expected it to execute nicely and write it properly. Well, in the line of the `while` loop, there was an error!!

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.
```

Any ideas about what could cause that?

Comment: _"instead of using loops"_. What do you think `while(...)` is?

Comment: @j08691 but this will be in a "library" that i will include using `<script src="">`, so I would have to bother only once doing all that. It's also shorter.

Comment: `document.write` expects `document` to be its `this` context. But you're invoking it with with `document.write` as `this`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why can't you do \[array\].forEach(console.log)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974228/why-cant-you-do-array-foreachconsole-log)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The context of `document.write` must be `document`, so your lib call to `.repeat` won't work on functions like `document.write` or `console.log` unless you account for a parameter to specify the context, or have already bound a context.

```js
Function.prototype.repeat = function(ctx, count, params) {
    //                               ^^^
    while(count--) this.apply(ctx, params);
    //                        ^^^
};

document.write.repeat(document, 4, ["Hi"]);
//                    ^^^^^^^^
```

or alternatively:

```js
Function.prototype.repeat = function(count, params) {
    while(count--) this.apply(this, params);
};
document.write.bind(document).repeat(4, ["Hi"]);
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll use the first option with the `ctx`. Is there an option to make the default ctx equal to `document` (and make it the 3rd parameter) and will it work for all the other functions?(For example alert)

Comment: @TheSuperCuber, you can write it however you'd like, as you're probably the only one who will be using it. I can tell you that a default context of `document` is a terrible choice, but so is creating a `repeat` function on `Function.prototype`.

Comment: basically what i want is an easy way to repeat a certain command a couple of times. Normally you would need to do `for(var i=0; i<5; i++)` for example, and using repeat it would be really quick and nice :D

Answer (score 0):

A lot of functions rely on being invoked in the context of a particular object in order to work correctly, and `document.write` is one of those functions. For example, this will fail because any `this` references within the function will be using the wrong `this` instead of `document`:

```
var w = document.write;
w("hello");
```

If you correctly invoke it in the context of `document`, it will work:

```js
Function.prototype.repeat = function(count) {
    while(count--) this.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
};

document.write.bind(document).repeat(4, "Hi");
```

See also: [why can't you do [array].forEach(console.log)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974228/why-cant-you-do-array-foreachconsole-log/28974287?s=2|0.0000#28974287)