# forEach loop on array with fat arrow

Tags: javascript, arrays, scala, lambda

I would like to print an array line by line with carriage return.

Simple implementation is `[1,2,3].forEach(function(x) {console.log(x)})` to get this as output

```
1
2
3
```

Now if I use the syntactic sugar of *ES6 fat arrows*,

```
michel$ node
> [1,2,3].forEach(x => console.log(x))
1
2
3
undefined
>
> [1,2,3].forEach(console.log)
1 0 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
2 1 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
3 2 [ 1, 2, 3 ]
undefined
```

When omitting the function parameter in the `forEach` callback, it looks like the second version is returning a cartesian product of itself.

In other functional languages like Scala this is totally ok, why is this "wrong" in JavaScript?

```
michel$ scala
scala> Array(1,2,3).foreach(x => println(x))
1
2
3

scala> Array(1,2,3).foreach(println)
1
2
3
```

Comment: And check `console.log(console.log)` You will get your answer.

Comment: I added a code sample in Scala to show you my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that this code here:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(console.log)
```

is the same as:

```
[1,2,3].forEach((value, index, array) => console.log(value, index, array))
```

It is not "wrong", it is just "unusual" in comparison to Scala or Java (method references) which seem to support method references with one single parameter. Javascript just seem to copy all parameters across to the referenced method (e.g. `console.log`) and if this method supports varargs, everything gets processed.

But if you do not like this behaviour you can fix it in Javascript. Create a simple function which accepts one single parameter:

```
function print(t) { console.log(t) }
```

and then execute:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(print)
```

And this prints the result, that will let you feel at home if you are coming from a Scala background:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639167/why-doesnt-console-log-work-when-passed-as-a-parameter-to-foreach
The answer is a bit different with the evolution of the JavaScript language.

Comment: *"it is just "unusual" in comparison to Scala or Java (method references) which seem to support method references with one single parameter."* There's nothing about method references in Java that intrinsically limits them to a single argument. This exact situation (`forEach` calling a method that supports varargs) could exist in Java.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the ES6 'fat' arrow Like this.

```
     const data = [1,2,3,4]

     data.forEach(item => {
         console.log(item)
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` passes multiple arguments to the callback, not just one: The item, its index, and the object on which `forEach` was called. Most implementations of `console.log` accept multiple parameters and output all of them. That's why `forEach(console.log)` outputs the entry (`1`), its index (`0`), and the array (`[ 1, 2, 3 ]`), then the next, etc.

With the arrow function, you're only using the first of those arguments.

---

Side note: `forEach(console.log)` also passes in `console.log` without ensuring that `this` during the call to `log` will be `console`. Some console implementations don't care, others do. So if you wanted that second form, you'd probably be better off with `forEach(console.log, console)`.

Comment: Ok maybe using fat arrows on `forEach` is bad approach for this reason and I should have got an ESLint warning ?

Comment: @JohnPoe: I don't understand what it is about using an arrow function that you think isn't right here?