# How to access ["X", "X", "O", "", "O"]

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

```
function Type(name, effectivenessData) {
    this.name = name;
    this.effectivenessData = effectivenessData;
}

var types = [
    new Type("Fire", ["X", "X", "O", "", "O"]),
    new Type("Water", ["O", "X", "X", "", ""]),
    new Type("Grass", ["X", "O", "X", "", ""]),
    new Type("Electric", ["", "O", "X", "X", ""]),
    new Type("Ice", ["X", "X", "O", "", "X"])
];

var getTypes = function getTypeNames() {
    return types.map(t => t.name);
}
```

My solutions: Hi all, I am using inner for loop to access effectivenessData but I get error saying length undefined. Can please somebody help me to understand how can I access the data here..or what am I doing wrong

```
for (var i =0; i < getTypes.length; i++) {
    console.log(getTypes[i].toString());

    for(var j=0; j< getTypes[i].effectivenessData; j++) {
console.log(getTypes[i].effectivenessData.[j]) // When I console log to check the data I get length undefined 
}
}
```

Comment: if `getTypes` is a function, you can't index into it with `[i]` or call `length` on it as if it were an array.

Comment: @ggorlen if so why I get the length and the data inside getTypes.length which is Fire, water, grass ...

Comment: I don't follow you. Running your code as it stands throws a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`. What are you seeing?

Comment: remove the dot (`.`) after `effectivenessData` in your console print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to print the types' `name`s in one loop and `effectivenessData` in another. You're attempting to index into `getTypes` as if it were an array, but it's a function which doesn't support such operations. Use `getTypes` to retrieve the array, then call `forEach` on the array to iterate over its elements:

```js
function Type(name, effectivenessData) {
    this.name = name;
    this.effectivenessData = effectivenessData;
}

var types = [
    new Type("Fire", ["X", "X", "O", "", "O"]),
    new Type("Water", ["O", "X", "X", "", ""]),
    new Type("Grass", ["X", "O", "X", "", ""]),
    new Type("Electric", ["", "O", "X", "X", ""]),
    new Type("Ice", ["X", "X", "O", "", "X"])
];

var getTypes = function () {
    return types.map(t => t.name);
};

getTypes().forEach(e => console.log(e));

types.forEach(e => console.log(e.effectivenessData));

// or, using a traditional loop:
for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
  console.log(types[i]);
}
```

As can be seen here, `getTypes` is a candidate for renaming (because it really returns type *names*) or removal (because it doesn't seem to add much to the code as it stands).

Comment: Don't use `forEach(console.log)`, use `forEach(x => console.log(x))`

Comment: May I ask why you suggest this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639167/why-doesnt-console-log-work-when-passed-as-a-parameter-to-foreach

Comment: That explains why it gets an error in some browsers. But even when it works, it prints extra output, because `forEach()` passes 3 arguments to the callback: the array element, the array index, and the whole array, so each of these gets logged.

Comment: Ah, OK. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to loop through:

```
function Type(name, effectivenessData) {
   this.name = name;
   this.effectivenessData = effectivenessData;
}

var types = [
    new Type("Fire", ["X", "X", "O", "", "O"]),
    new Type("Water", ["O", "X", "X", "", ""]),
    new Type("Grass", ["X", "O", "X", "", ""]),
    new Type("Electric", ["", "O", "X", "X", ""]),
   new Type("Ice", ["X", "X", "O", "", "X"])
];

for(var i = 0; i < types.length; i++){
   console.log(types[i].effectivenessData)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `getTypes()[i]` instead of `getTypes[i]` since it is a function.

Answer (score 0):

`getTypes` must be invoked e.g `getTypes()` and its return value should be stored in a `var` so that the iteration code is cleaner.